# R Notebooks - Can I paste an image into a notebook?

Tags: r

I'm creating my first R Notbook (I've created several R Markdown documents). I realize I can link to an image using the following syntax:

```
![This is the caption](/url/of/image.png)
```

However, is there a way I can paste an image into a notebook? I'd like to create some notebooks that will contain quite a few images, that I'd like to copy from some source and then paste into my notebook. I really don't want to have to same each image first if I don't have to. I suspect I'm not able to do this because the Pandoc documentation doesn't mention, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: does `knitr::include_graphics(path = "/url/of/image.png")` do what you want?

Comment: No because the image must be saved to disk first. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'd say no way....